# How to display selected Dropdown values index number in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

My DropDown working fine. I can Select item from my dropdown and also showing the selected item in my App. Now, ***Instead of displaying the selected item from dropdown I want to display index number of that particular Item.***

[image: Example image]

My Dropdown item List

```
    List<String> qualities = [
    "Creativity",
    "Commitment",
    "Planning",
    "Optimism",
    "Innovative"
  ];
```

Empty List. Here I'm storing selected items, then displaying using for loop

```
 List<String> selectedItem_ArrayList = []; //Storing DropDown selected data
```

My dropDown

```
DropdownButton<String>(
                          underline: Container(),
                          icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                          iconSize: 24,
                          isExpanded: true,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            if (!selectedItem_ArrayList.contains(value)) {//=============================================>>>Items Disable after selection
                              setState(() {
                                selectedQualities = value!;
                                selectedItem_ArrayList.add(selectedQualities);
                              });
                            }//==============================================>>>Adding item into list
                          },
                          value: selectedQualities,
                          items: qualities.map((dropdownValue) => DropdownMenuItem(
                                    child: Text(
                                      dropdownValue,
                                      maxLines: 2,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: selectedItem_ArrayList.contains(dropdownValue)? Colors.grey: null,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    value: dropdownValue,
                                  ))
                              .toList(),
                        ),
```

Displaying Selected Item from drop Dropdown

```
 Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  for (var i = 0; i < selectedItem_ArrayList.length; i++)
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text(selectedItem_ArrayList[i]), //### here I want to show index number of that particular selected item.
                      trailing: GestureDetector(//#################### remove specific index item
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedItem_ArrayList.remove(selectedItem_ArrayList[i]);
                          });
                        },
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.delete_rounded,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
              )
```

Using `indexOf` its only displaing index number `0` for every item selection

```
title: Text(selectedItem_ArrayList[i].indexOf(selectedItem_ArrayList[i]).toString()),
```

Comment: can you explain your question what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get that you're wanting to display the index number of the element in the original qualities list ?

The simplest way there is to either do a check on the original list, or to have a index table to quickly get the needed index.

In the first case, all you would do is call something like `qualities.indexOf(selectedItem_ArrayList[i])`, and it should do the trick.

If you want an index table, i would probably convert the qualities list to a Map<String, int> :

```dart
final qualities = <String, int>{
  "Creativity": 0,
  "Commitment": 1,
  "Planning": 2,
  "Optimism": 3,
  "Innovative": 4,
};
```

Then, instead of using `qualities.map` in the DropdownButton, you would use `qualities.keys.map`.
Once you need to get to the index back, you can just call `qualities[selectedItem_ArrayList[i])`.

As a quick note, your `selectedItem_ArrayList[i].indexOf(selectedItem_ArrayList[i])` doesn't do what you expect it to do, as you do indexOf on a specific element on your list, which means you do it on a String. Currently, it returns 0, as the Pattern you pass in argument of the indexOf is the string itself, so it validates that the Pattern is found from the beginning of the String. If it didn't, it would return -1.

If you wanted to display the index of the element in the select items list, you would do `selectedItem_ArrayList.indexOf(selectedItem_ArrayList[i])`.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

You just have to do

```
Text('$i');
```

Or

```
Text(selectedItem_ArrayList.indexOf(selectedItem_ArrayList[i]));
```

You are getting 0 in you code because you are using `indexOf()` on a String that doesn't contains what you are looking for so it returns 0.